# Tools and techniques for enlarging round hole in brick wall

Tags: drill, brick, powertools, hole, technique

I have a new kitchen hood with a vent duct slightly larger than the existing one and I need to "roundly" enlarge the hole.

What would be the best power tool(s) and accessories to be used for this work?

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: How large does the hole have to be? What are the walls made of?

Comment: the whole needs to be enlarged by 3 mm (1/8 inch) all around. The walls are made of hollow brick with a layer of .. mortar/concrete? at the inner side

Comment: Large hammer and chisel and just pick the hole larger

Comment: @Chris: I did something similar, I used a flat head screwdriver with a hammer and chiseled delicately away but thought to myself to ask on this site for opinions though.

Comment: you can pre-drill in front of large chunks to control splitting and make it easier to chisel. if you don't care about the bit you can drill the whole thing out like a dentist...

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need a power tool.
Just one of those rough files is all you need.

Hope this helps.

Take care.

[image: coarse files]

Comment: Be sure to get a rasp designed for stone… the wood ones won’t last long.

Answer (score 1):

1/8" isn't much to enlarge.

I'd probably go with a 4.5" angle grinder with a masonry grinding disc something with a large kerf.